# How can I extract abbreviations from a file using Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I need to extract certain Abbreviations from a file such as ABS,TVS,and PERL. Any abbreviations which are in uppercase letters. I'd preferably like to do this with a regular expression. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how are you going to determine whether a word is an abbreviation? there must be a database of some sort , like another file with all the abbreviations you can get, or a database where you can query.

Comment: A nieve implementation might treat any string of uppercase characters longer than 2 characters as an abbreviation.

Comment: I would also add an upper limit, because if it's say longer than 5 or 6 characters then I'd doubt it's an abbreviation ;)

Comment: FORTRAN was once an abbreviation...

Comment: @fortran: What about TMTOWTDI?

Answer (score 4):

It would have been nice to hear what part you were particularly having trouble with.

```
my %abbr;
open my $inputfh, '<', 'filename'
    or die "open error: $!\n";
while ( my $line = readline($inputfh) ) {
    while ( $line =~ /\b([A-Z]{2,})\b/g ) {
        $abbr{$1}++;
    }
}

for my $abbr ( sort keys %abbr ) {
    print "Found $abbr $abbr{$abbr} time(s)\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading text to be searched from standard input and writing
all abbreviations found to standard output, separated by spaces:

```
my $text;
# Slurp all text
{ local $/ = undef; $text = <>; }
# Extract all sequences of 2 or more uppercase characters
my @abbrevs = $text =~ /\b([[:upper:]]{2,})\b/g;
# Output separated by spaces
print join(" ", @abbrevs), "\n";
```

Note the use of the POSIX character class [:upper:], which will match
*all* uppercase characters, not just English ones (A-Z).

Comment: Put `\b` at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 2):

Untested:

```
my %abbr;
open (my $input, "<", "filename")
  || die "open: $!";
for ( < $input > ) {
  while (s/([A-Z][A-Z]+)//) {
    $abbr{$1}++;
  }
}
```

Modified it to look for at least two consecutive capital letters.

Comment: no need to substitute there, nor to read in the whole file before processing any (though you've got a bug: that's a glob(), not a readline(), due to the extra spaces).

Comment: You're probably right, but the editor didn't allow it without the spaces. I suspect the "lt dollar" sequence got cut out without the spaces.

Comment: You need to tell the editor that you're in charge - or perhaps get a different editor.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %abbrs = ();

while(<>){
    my @words = split ' ', $_;

    foreach my $word(@words){
        $word =~ /([A-Z]{2,})/ && $abbrs{$1}++;
    }
}

# %abbrs now contains all abreviations
```

Comment: Missing a `$word=~` there.  For kicks, you could say: `$word =~ y/A-Z//c or $abbrs{$word}++;`.

Comment: i need to extract only...abbreviations like ABC or BAV for example i have also like ABC123,CMV002 in my document it also extracts that... i just want to extract only ABC and CMV in this case.. can you help me?

Comment: OK, changed it so it does that

Comment: Alternatively, if the numbers always come after the abbreviation, you can use /^([A-Z]+)[0-9]*$/

Comment: i have a problem this /^([A-Z]+)[0-9]*$/ extracts even digits at starting... say for ex
017_ABC_EFG....